# Publishing DLLs azure

Tags: dll, azure

I've published my first asp.net project to azure could.
This project uses MySql DLLs.
Locally, I added the references and the site work.
When publishing, I get an exception which mean those DLLs weren't published with the site, and therefore, missing.

Please assist,
Thx

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the DLL, go to properties, and make sure "Copy to output directory" is set to "Copy if Newer / Copy Always".

Also make sure the dll is compiled as 64-bit, otherwise you'll get a wrong format error.

Answer (score 0):

If your app works locally but you're getting an assembly not found exception after deploying to Azure, make sure your MySql DLLs exist in the .cspkg file that is generated by the Azure project.  A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571600/546483) of mine explains how to examine the contents of the .cspkg file.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into that file and indded, those DLLs are missing. How can I verify they will be included in the publish?

Comment: Go to your asp.net project references and make sure Copy Local is set to true for the MySql DLLs.