# Web.config not being created in Azure package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, assembly-binding-redirect

I'm trying to run an existing working Web app in Azure, using SDK tools version 2.2. The Web app works fine running as a 'normal' MVC 4 site, and also runs fine in the Azure emulator locally. The app has been designed to run either installed on a server or as a Web role.

I've been trying all weekend to publish it to Azure, but always get the

```
Server Error in '/' Application
```

message. By enabling remote desktop I'm able to have a look at the event log, and this is the message I get.

(It follows after this, but for tl;dr purposes, I think the binding redirect isn't being picked up because the main complaint is that System.Web.Mvc 3.0.0.0 cannot be loaded.)

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 11/3/2013 10:36:10 AM 
Event time (UTC): 11/3/2013 10:36:10 AM 
Event ID: 2be088053f02484e95f3f17fcd95b67e 
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1273337584/ROOT-1-130279485699443947 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: F:\sitesroot\0\ 
Machine name: RD00155D463D30 

Process information: 
Process ID: 1536 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
Exception message: The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type    Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
at Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap.Initialize()

Request information: 
Request URL: http://blizzard-propressroom.cloudapp.net/ 
Request path: / 
User host address: 176.27.246.0 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 5 
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
```

I tried unloading ELMAH in case it was that, but I still get the same inability to load MVC version 3.0.0.0.

Now of course this makes some sense because I'm running MVC 4, and that's what I have in my package.

Running v4 isn't a problem locally, of course, because my Web.config has:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

But apparently Azure WebRoles can't use Web.config (and sure enough, if I find the source through Remote Desktop there's an almost empty Web.config file there).

I've seen suggestions that I need an app.config, which I've tried (just a direct copy of the web.config) and Copy set to Copy Always. I can see there's a copy of that in my bin folder.

This all seems like a very confusing hoop to jump through to me, but it also seems like the rules for binding redirects on Azure change with each SDK version, so there's a load of conflicting information online.

So after a very lengthy post: **Please does anyone know what I need to do to tell Azure about Binding Redirects?** (and do you agree that this is in fact the problem?)

**Update**

Thanks to @viperguynaz for some suggestions, but to confirm that my System.Web.MVC is marked as copy true. This morning I tried deleting my Azure project entirely, and using the Convert to Windows Azure Cloud Service Project option in Visual Studio in case anything had gone wrong initially. But I've still got the same problem.

Using Remote Desktop on the Azure service, I've gone to E:\sitesroot\0. The Web.config there is virtually empty. Just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="F7FA540B4DFD82E5BB196B95D15FF81F6FC418E967F01A1C60FB407A84615031" validation="SHA1" validationKey="6FC418E967F01A1C60FB407A84615031902C0D9A9DE62168764FF0DCE537184F0535D5D9AD66DEDC6FC418E967F01A1C60FB407A84615031902C0D9A97DC1ABF" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

There's no sign of my web.config. But everything else is present and correct, including my Web.config in the Views folder.

My latest build and publish told me something very interesting during the build process:

```
warning WAT153: The web project 'xxx' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll.
warning WAT153: The web project 'xxx' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll.
warning WAT153: The web project 'xxx' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Razor.dll
warning WAT153: The web project 'xxx' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.
warning WAT153: The web project 'xxx' is dependent on the following MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll.
```

And for all of these:

```
MVC assemblies must be added to the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
```

Now this seems clear, *except* that they are all set to be copied with the project, and my project is set as a web role (as the link suggests). There's talk in the link of having to create a startup folder with ASP Net MVC installation, and adding a WebStart cs but I'm feeling this is out-of-date advice, otherwise why wouldn't "Convert to Windows Azure Cloud Service Project" do these jobs?

**Update 2**

OK, it looks like it is that my Web.config file isn't being packaged up for some reason. I dug out a project I have successfully installed in Azure, opened the package file in 7-zip and found there was a Web.config file bundled with it. There's no such web.config file in this problem project. I'll start trying to work out why.

I've also updated the problem title to reflect this info. It's almost certainly the cause of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is the same situation as [Azure ASP.NET MVC Web.Config Deployment Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570016/azure-asp-net-mvc-web-config-deployment-issue)

My web.config had a deploy value of "none" (somehow) so wasn't being included in the package, meaning an almost empty default one was created instead.

I changed the deploy type to "Content" (using Properties on Web.config) and it's now being bundled.

Comment: I spent a lot hour stuck on this. I couldn't promote package updates and hence site was erring out. That is until I came across this comment. So, you comment still helping some, almost three years later :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you found the correct web.config in your RDP session. The site (web app) is stored on a virtual hard drive, typically e:\sitesroot\0 or f:\sitesroot\0 - you can confirm this by opening IIS and inspecting the sites physical directory.  In that directory, you will find the web.config that was transformed during your build/package process.  This is the web.config used by your site.  Start your troubleshooting by adding `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in the `<system.web>` section.  Then browse the site locally from IIS. My suspicion is that you don't have the System.Web.Mvc set to `Copy Local = True`.  Next, your web.config  build settings should be:

- Build Action = Content
- Copy to Output Directory = Do Not Copy (you don't want the web.config file in your bin directory).

As a general rule of thumb for Azure deployments, if the path to an assembly your app uses isn't located in `..\Reference Assemblies\..`, then you most likely need to set `Copy Local = True` to include the assembly in your bin directory.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my original question with some aspects of this. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your `.csproj` file you have the file included as such or else it will be ignored

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <Content Include="App_Data\XMLDocument.xml" />
    <Content Include="Areas\HelpPage\HelpPage.css" />
    <Content Include="Areas\HelpPage\Views\Web.config" />   <----- THIS LINE
    <Content Include="Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\Api.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\ApiGroup.cshtml" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

(added due to suggest edit queue being full)